# how to change time picker format 12hr in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

when i am trying to print in label time format would be change to 24 hr i need 12 hr. 
trying to change the output format of time picker but I couldn't solve.

here is my code

Xaml:

```
<TimePicker x:Name="timepic" Format="hh:mm:tt"></TimePicker>
  <Label x:Name="time"/>
```

cs

```
  time.Text = timepic.Time.ToString();
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

by default, `ToString()` will format it using whatever your locale settings are.  If you want to override that, provide a format specifier

```
time.Text = timepic.Time.ToString("hh:mm:tt");
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert DateTime objects into 12h or 24h, you can use these methods.

```
public static string ToFormat12h(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd, hh:mm:ss tt");
    }

    public static string ToFormat24h(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd, HH:mm:ss");
    }
```

So, in your case:

```
time.Text = timepic.Time.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
```

Comment: Can you apply this depending on the time setting on your phone?